# Столкнулся с проблемой при переносе с Vue.js на Nuxt.js. не пойму в чем ошибка

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

делаю перенос своего проекта с Vue.js на Nuxt.js и столкнулся с таким проблемой. есть страница "Открытые диалоги", и в этом странице пользователи заданное время могут задать вопрос администраторам проекта. так вот проблема в том что на vue те же самое условия и коды хорошо работает и ограничение тоже, а nuxt не обрабатывает ошибку.  то есть

## nuxt.config.js

```
axios: {
     baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL
},
```

## utilities.js

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

function setAuthorizationHeader(axios) {
  axios.setHeader('X-CSRFTOKEN', Cookies.get('csrftoken'));
  return
}
export { setAuthorizationHeader }
```

## store

```
import {setAuthorizationHeader} from '@/middleware/utilities'

......
  async commentNew({commit}, data) {
    try {
      setAuthorizationHeader(this.$axios);
      const url = '/comments/create/'
      const response = await this.$axios.post(url, data)
      return response.data
    } catch (error) {
      throw error
    }
  },
......
```

## компоненте

```
        async saveMessage() {
                this.error = null;
                this.saving = true;
                this.myMessageSend = true;

                try {
                    const obj = {
                        body: this.body,
                        parentType: this.parentType,
                        parentID: Number(this.parentID)
                    };
                    this.body = '';
                    const response = await this.$store.dispatch("common/commentNew", obj);
                    console.log('saveMessage, успешно-----' , response);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log('saveMessage, ошибка -------', error);
                    console.log('saveMessage, ошибка response------', error.response);
                } finally {
                    this.saving = false;
                }
            },
```

когда событие который на компоненте срабатывает должен вернуть мне ответ как у vue но nuxt выдает undefined

это на vue выдает так ошибку
[image: это на vue выдает так ошибку]

а это на nuxt
[image: а это на nuxt]

почему undefined? почему когда сервер вернул ответ 403  он не упал сразу на catch? странно что когда сервер возвращает ответы 400, 401, 403, 500 от не подает на catch а продолжает код и выдает responsive.data выдает ошибку

Comment: `const response = await this.$axios.$post(url, data)`
`return response;`, попробуйте так

Comment: Не братан, я так пробовал. та же проблема

Comment: Так пишет же `403` - надо проверить и убедиться, что есть доступ (передан токен в заголовке). В том смысле, что руками проверить, что он точно там. Вывести в консоль при его чтении из кук и перед отправкой вывести содержимое заголовков. И убедиться, что параметры на своем месте. Так же большой вопрос по адресу обращения - он точне не изменяется при переносе логики на сервер? может там локалхост?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему:

> ```
> $axios.interceptors.response.use(undefined, async (error) => { 
>   return Promise.reject(error) // возвращаю все ошибки
> });
> ```